# Get max and average values from an array of dictionaries swift

Tags: arrays, list, max, average

I have an array (filled by NSUserDefaults: Defaults.arrayForKey("onLine") as! [[String:AnyObject]]) and how can I get the average and max values from SPEED?

I Tried online.max!["SPEED"] but didn't work

Any helps?

[["LONGITUDE: ": -122.02211045, "BEARING: ": 263.41, "LATITUDE: ": 37.32475565, "SPEED: ": 3.76, "TIMESTAMP: ": 2016-10-19T02:09:49.535Z], ["LONGITUDE: ": -122.02230437, "BEARING: ": 270.15, "LATITUDE: ": 37.32475499, "SPEED: ": 3.15, "TIMESTAMP: ": 2016-10-19T02:09:54.518Z], ["LONGITUDE: ": -122.02249983, "BEARING: ": 265.56, "LATITUDE: ": 37.32475587, "SPEED: ": 3.27, "TIMESTAMP: ": 2016-10-19T02:09:59.516Z]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it my self with this code

```
speedArray.append(userLocation.speed * 1.94384)
        let avgSpeed = speedArray.reduce(0, combine: +) / Double(speedArray.count)
        let maxSpeed = speedArray.maxElement()
```